# Request headers added in OWIN not present when using IIS with URL Rewrite module

Tags: iis, owin, url-rewrite-module, request-headers, owin-middleware

**Context:** Custom API Gateway implemented in ASP.NET and OWIN, hosted in IIS. Reverse-proxy functionality is implemented by using the IIS URL Rewrite rules. OWIN Middleware is used to check and/or manipulate requests (e.g. authorization) and responses (e.g. CORS)

**Issue:** When using OWIN middleware to add/modify request headers(e.g. `context.Request.Headers.Add/Set/Append`), they are simply not present when it reaches the downstream API.

**Observations:**

- The issue is only with *request* headers. Adding *response* headers works fine.
- The OWIN calls modifying the headers seem to be registered and logged by IIS:
  [image: IIS logs showing the header is being set]
  (result of `context.Request.Headers.Append("X-Test-Last-Middleware", "Testing")`)
- When the custom headers are added client-side (before the request even reaches the OWIN gateway), they reach the downstream API just fine
- I've tried allowing the headers in IIS URL Rewrite server variables using the `HTTP_X_Test_Last_Middleware` syntax/convention, but that did not help
- If added manually onto the IIS Rewrite rule (as a server variable using the same convention), the header is present downstream (provided the server variable has been allowed). This does however not suit our use-case.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Putting dynamic information to the request (headers) before it reaches the downstream API is a must.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the full code for your middleware?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can, actually, but I can try to make an equivalent example tomorrow. The middleware is working within the OWIN app. E.g. if a request doesn't go further downstream,    but to a controller, the headers are there. They can naturally also be seen in subsequent middleware invocations.

Comment: @valorl Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue

Comment: @TerranceJackson We didn't figure it out. Ended up implementing an IIS HTTP Module in the ASP.NET app instead of an OWIN middleware to add the headers we needed to add. That worked. *shrug*